# BEING a responsible worker

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Can I use 'being' in the following ways?

- **“Being a responsible worker I can not let this happen.”**
- **“You shouldn't talk to him like that being his employee.”**

Do they make sense and sound natural?

Comment: Yes, it's okay. In your example, "Being a responsible worker" means "As I am a responsible worker".